# Downgrading play-services-maps from 10.0.1 to (9.6.1, 9.8.0) causes app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, gradle, maps

I'm not using libraries that would normally have that many methods to require multi dex. What are other normal issues that may cause this?

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle here !

Answer (score 0):

For starters, This could be due to the different Major versions i.e. "10" in 10.0.1 usually this signifies something is broken in the API specification from the previous one.